# How to create clickable icons in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to just create a clickable icon in `angularjs`. It works so far, but the link element changes the location of the page, which it should not.

```
<a ng-href="#" ng-click="callbackMethod()" target="_self" class="icon" title="test">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
</a>
```

Question: how can I prevent the location change? Or is an `<a>` tag not the correct element here?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href ng-click="callbackMethod()"  class="icon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
</a>
```

or:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" ng-click="callbackMethod()" style="cursor:pointer;"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to create just an icon that does something when clicked, don't use the `<a>` tag, just use a `<div>` or `<img>`. An anchor tag is meant semantically aid navigation. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass an empty string to your `href` attribute. This will prevent your browser from changing its location.

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="callbackMethod()" target="_self" class="icon" title="test">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the ng-href if u want it to stay on the same page . Add whatever functionality you want within the function and assign it to ng-click

```
<a ng-click="callbackMethod()" target="_self" class="icon" title="test">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
```